# ordering responses based on individual dates

Tags: r, sorting, date, dplyr

I have time series data in my data frame that is organized by subject ID and response date, where each subject responded for 7 days but starting and ending on different days. I need to come up with a variable for response day that indexes by each subjects' first day. See example:

```
id  response
101 11/2/2017
101 11/2/2017
101 11/3/2017
101 11/3/2017
101 11/3/2017
101 11/3/2017
102 12/14/2017
102 12/15/2017
```

and would like to create the column "day"

```
id  response    day
101 11/2/2017   1
101 11/2/2017   1
101 11/3/2017   2
101 11/3/2017   2
101 11/3/2017   2
101 11/3/2017   2
102 12/14/2017  1
102 12/15/2017  2
```

I've been trying to do this in dplyr and can't find the right code. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

One solution can be by simply use `group_by` and difference from 1st record of a group. Since the `response` is of type `Date`, we need to `add` to evaluate same day response as `1`. The example.

```
df <- read.table(text = "id  response
101 '11/2/2017'
101 '11/2/2017'
101 '11/3/2017'
101 '11/3/2017'
101 '11/3/2017'
101 '11/3/2017'
102 '12/14/2017'
102 '12/15/2017'", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df$response <- as.Date(df$response, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, response) %>%
  mutate(day = response - first(response)+1)

     id response   day   
  <int> <date>     <time>
1   101 2017-11-02 1     
2   101 2017-11-02 1     
3   101 2017-11-03 2     
4   101 2017-11-03 2     
5   101 2017-11-03 2     
6   101 2017-11-03 2     
7   102 2017-12-14 1     
8   102 2017-12-15 2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dense_rank` from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr). The `mutate` and `arrange` calls here are just to make sure the date are in the right order. You can ignore that if you are certain the date are in the right order.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(response = mdy(response)) %>%
  arrange(id, response) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(day = dense_rank(response)) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#      id response     day
#   <int> <date>     <int>
# 1   101 2017-11-02     1
# 2   101 2017-11-02     1
# 3   101 2017-11-03     2
# 4   101 2017-11-03     2
# 5   101 2017-11-03     2
# 6   101 2017-11-03     2
# 7   102 2017-12-14     1
# 8   102 2017-12-15     2
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "id  response
101 '11/2/2017'
                  101 '11/2/2017'
                  101 '11/3/2017'
                  101 '11/3/2017'
                  101 '11/3/2017'
                  101 '11/3/2017'
                  102 '12/14/2017'
                  102 '12/15/2017'",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Interesting to know about `dense_rank`. Thx,

Answer (score 1):

We can `group_by` id then just take the response as a factor and convert to numeric.

```
dat%>%group_by(id)%>%mutate(day=as.numeric(factor(response))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id   response   day
  <int>      <chr> <dbl>
1   101  11/2/2017     1
2   101  11/2/2017     1
3   101  11/3/2017     2
4   101  11/3/2017     2
5   101  11/3/2017     2
6   101  11/3/2017     2
7   102 12/14/2017     1
8   102 12/15/2017     2
```

if the dates are not arranged then you can add the levels to the factor:
`dat%>%group_by(id)%>%mutate(day=as.numeric(factor(response,unique(response))))`

Comment: Your 2nd solution didnt work for me. Could you please check it once? Thx.

Comment: Did it produce an error? I just used it and it worked with the example you gave.

Comment: For me `day` evaluates as `NA` for all rows. Is it because the `response` column has been converted to `Date` type?

Comment: No I have not converted it to date yet . If you look at the table above, respose is of class character. So your response should be class character.. Copy the data given as `df` or `dat` and use it. And you will see that it works.

Comment: Correct mate. If I dont convert it to `Date` then it worked but the problem is that if there missing dates then it cannot consider it. e.g. `11/2/2017`, `11/3/2017`, `11/5/2017' will result as `1, 2, 3` but it should be `1, 2, 4`. Though OP is not very clear about the rule either.

Comment: That s a quick fix. I never saw that in your question. Am so sorry. Give me a minute

Comment: Sorry mate. I'm not the one who posted question:-) I'm another person who has already added an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

*If* the rows are already ordered by `id` and `response`, `data.table`'s `rleid()` function can be used:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, day := rleid(response), by = id][]
```

> ```
>     id   response day
> 1: 101  11/2/2017   1
> 2: 101  11/2/2017   1
> 3: 101  11/3/2017   2
> 4: 101  11/3/2017   2
> 5: 101  11/3/2017   2
> 6: 101  11/3/2017   2
> 7: 102 12/14/2017   1
> 8: 102 12/15/2017   2
> ```

The correct row order is important for `rleid()` to return the expected result.

If the rows are *not* already ordered, the data string in the `response` column needs to be coerced to class `Date` first. Then it can be used to order the rows.

For instance, with an unordered dataset `DF2`

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(123L)
DF2 <- setDT(DF)[sample.int(.N)]
DF2
```

> ```
>     id   response
> 1: 101  11/3/2017
> 2: 101  11/3/2017
> 3: 102 12/15/2017
> 4: 101  11/3/2017
> 5: 101  11/3/2017
> 6: 101  11/2/2017
> 7: 101  11/2/2017
> 8: 102 12/14/2017
> ```

```
DF2[, response := mdy(response)][order(response), day := rleid(response), by = id][]
```

> ```
>     id   response day
> 1: 101 2017-11-03   2
> 2: 101 2017-11-03   2
> 3: 102 2017-12-15   2
> 4: 101 2017-11-03   2
> 5: 101 2017-11-03   2
> 6: 101 2017-11-02   1
> 7: 101 2017-11-02   1
> 8: 102 2017-12-14   1
> ```

The original row order of `DF2` has not been changed, but the days are numbered as requested. This is difficult to see unless printed in the right order:

```
DF2[order(id, response)]
```

> ```
>     id   response day
> 1: 101 2017-11-02   1
> 2: 101 2017-11-02   1
> 3: 101 2017-11-03   2
> 4: 101 2017-11-03   2
> 5: 101 2017-11-03   2
> 6: 101 2017-11-03   2
> 7: 102 2017-12-14   1
> 8: 102 2017-12-15   2
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread(
  "id  response
  101 11/2/2017
  101 11/2/2017
  101 11/3/2017
  101 11/3/2017
  101 11/3/2017
  101 11/3/2017
  102 12/14/2017
  102 12/15/2017"
)
```